# Using python index function on html document

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The below script looks through an `html` document. Firstly it replaces certain text with different text. This part works as expected. The next job is to split the text between ``` <font>``</font> ``` tags into groups. And place them, the groups, within `[]`. This works as expected. Heres were it falls over. It should use these groups `[]` to compare each groups `Entity Id..` and if a match/duplicate is found I would like it to remove the relative group. Unfortunately, this script isn't removing the groups with duplicates, and there are more than enough in there. In some cases > 100 duplicates. They are dynamic so there could be many different `Entity Id...xxx` all with duplicates. Rather than deleting every group that includes a duplicate, Id like to keep 1 group for each duplicate `Entity Id...` Does my issue lie within this

```
for group in groups[1:]:
    if group[1] == groups[groups.index(group)-1][1]:
        groups.remove(group)
```

As I understand, it uses `group[1]` which is the last `Entity Id...123456` within the document as a lookup value against `groups[groups.index(group)-1][1]:` which will include every `Entity Id` within the document thanks to the `Index` function. But as `group[1]` is not in an 'Index' function it is only using the last `Entity Id...` as a lookup? Do I need to include an `Index` within  `if group[1] ==`?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib
import os

svdir = ''
filename = 'something.html'


with open(r'something.html', 'r') as f:
   html_string = f.read()


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string)

target = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'Serial#.........'))
for v in target:                                
    v.replace_with(v.replace('Serial#.........','Note Id.....'))

target1 = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'Cust#...........'))
for v in target1:
    v.replace_with(v.replace('Cust#...........','Entity Id...'))

target2 = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'Customer Name...'))
for v in target2:
    v.replace_with(v.replace('Customer Name...','Entity Name.'))

target3 = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'BILL TO NO NAME.'))
for v in target3:
    v.replace_with(v.replace('BILL TO NO NAME.','Note Detail.'))

target4 = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'FIXED DATE......'))
for v in target4:
    v.replace_with(v.replace('FIXED DATE......','Create Date.'))


data = soup.select_one('font')
targets = data.text.replace('Note Id','xxxNote Id').split('xxx')
groups = [target.strip().split('\n') for target in targets[1:]]
for group in groups[1:]:
    if group[1] == groups[groups.index(group)-1][1]:
        groups.remove(group)
new_ts = '\n'
for group in groups:
    new_ts += '\n'.join(group)+'\n\n'
data.string.replace_with(new_ts)
    
print(soup)

sv_path = os.path.join(svdir, filename)
fp = open(sv_path, 'w')
fp.write(str(soup))   
fp.close()
```

here is some sample html, just as a guide for structure

```
<font>

##This is a group##
Serial#......... 123456789101234567
Cust#........... 123456
Customer Name... Joe Rogan
BILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 000000 - Some Company
FIXED DATE...... 01/01/00

##This is another group##
Serial#......... 765432110987654321
Cust#........... 123456
Customer Name... Nate Diaz
BILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 000001 - Some other company
FIXED DATE...... 01/01/00

Serial#......... 123456789101234567
Cust#........... 123451
Customer Name... Someone Famous
BILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 000012 - My Company
FIXED DATE...... 01/01/00

Serial#......... 7765897411126
Cust#........... 123456
Customer Name... John Giles
BILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 000123 - Sole trader PTY LTD
FIXED DATE...... 01/01/00

Serial#......... 12345665432112345
Cust#........... 000001
Customer Name... Mary Mack
BILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 000245 - Hello.PTY.LTD
FIXED DATE...... 01/01/00`
</font>
```

here is what Im hoping to acheive

```
<font>
Note Id..... 123456789101234567
Entity Id... 123456
Entity Name. Joe Rogan
Note Detail. Bill To: 000000 - Some Company
Create Date. 01/01/00

Note Id..... 12345665432112345
Entity Id... 000001
Entity Name. Ned Flanders
Note Detail. Bill To: 000002 - Some other big company
Create Date. 01/01/00

Note Id..... 123456789101234567
Entity Id... 123451
Entity Name. Someone Famous
Note Detail. Bill To: 000012 - My Company
Create Date. 01/01/00
    

</font>
```

Comment: Not scraping, its a file from local directory

Comment: Why in exptected outcome are two groups with Cust# 000001?

Comment: Im sorry that was a mistake on my part. Thanks for picking that up. I have edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_data = '''<font>
Serial#......... 123456789101234567
Cust#........... 123456
Customer Name... Joe Rogan
BILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 000000 - Some Company
FIXED DATE...... 01/01/00

Serial#......... 765432110987654321
Cust#........... 123456
Customer Name... Nate Diaz
BILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 000001 - Some other company
FIXED DATE...... 01/01/00

Serial#......... 123456789101234567
Cust#........... 123451
Customer Name... Someone Famous
BILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 000012 - My Company
FIXED DATE...... 01/01/00

Serial#......... 7765897411126
Cust#........... 123456
Customer Name... John Giles
BILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 000123 - Sole trader PTY LTD
FIXED DATE...... 01/01/00

Serial#......... 12345665432112345
Cust#........... 000001
Customer Name... Mary Mack
BILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 000245 - Hello.PTY.LTD
FIXED DATE...... 01/01/00
</font>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')

groups = soup.font.text.replace('Serial#', 'xxxSerial#').split('xxx')

seen, out = set(), []
for g in groups:
    m = re.search(r'Cust#.*?(\d+)\s*$', g, flags=re.M)
    if not m:
        continue
    if m.group(1) not in seen:
        seen.add(m.group(1))
        out.append(g.strip())

soup.find('font').string.replace_with('\n' + '\n\n'.join(out) + '\n')

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<font>
Serial#......... 123456789101234567
Cust#........... 123456
Customer Name... Joe Rogan
BILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 000000 - Some Company
FIXED DATE...... 01/01/00

Serial#......... 123456789101234567
Cust#........... 123451
Customer Name... Someone Famous
BILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 000012 - My Company
FIXED DATE...... 01/01/00

Serial#......... 12345665432112345
Cust#........... 000001
Customer Name... Mary Mack
BILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 000245 - Hello.PTY.LTD
FIXED DATE...... 01/01/00
</font>
```